# How to solve a crossdomain policy security exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, policy

I have been trying to create a C# IRC client, I've got everything working, and when connecting to some networks it throws a socket policy exception as follows:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Unable to connect, as no valid
>   crossdomain policy was found at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect_internal (IntPtr sock,
>   System.Net.SocketAddress sa, System.Int32& error, Boolean
>   requireSocketPolicyFile) [0x00000] in :0 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP,
>   Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in :0 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP)
>   [0x00000] in :0 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint
>   remote_end_point) [0x00000] in :0 at
>   system.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[]
>   ipAddresses, Int32 port) [0x00000] in :0

Here's the code I am using to connect:

```
//connect the client
client = new TcpClient(serverAddress, serverPort);
```

The moment it tries to connect to most IRC servers it throws that exception, but for some it doesn't, as you probably realize I need the client to connect to any irc server that allows it.

I have tried searching for solutions on Google but all it came up with was Silverlight exceptions, I am not using Silverlight. I've been trying to resolve this for a week with no luck, I've been programming for 8 years, and I am quite adept at solving problems, but this is beyond me so any help is appreciated.

Regards, Amy.

Comment: How does the Server provide the connection?
Are you using AppDomains, which may be not allowed to access Network resources?

Comment: Where is your code running? Is this a desktop app (console / WinForms / WPF), an in-browser-rich-client app (Silverlight), a server app (ASP.NET / other)?

Comment: ive already said its not silverlight, it's using C# .NET on desktop, but it can also run in browsers, I get the same problem both on desktop and browsers though. and idk about the server, because im not making the server, im only connecting to it. I know the protocol so I can get the client responding to messages appropriately which I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the assembly as an administrator? If that works then it's a security issue and you need to specify the permission your program requires. So, if "Run as Admin" works, check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.socketpermissionattribute%28v=VS.110%29.aspx